# Invalid free() / delete / delete[] / realloc() error in assignment operator

Tags: c++, valgrind, free

I am new to programming and when I am trying to run a program using Valgrind I was getting an error like this. I googled hours to solve this problem. please can you tell me where I am going wrong. Hope there is some mistake near assignment operator.

Error:

```
==5130== Invalid read of size 8
==5130==    at 0x400CFD: std::passwd::~passwd() (passwd.c++:18)
==5130==    by 0x400C06: main (p1.c++:21)
==5130==  Address 0x5a1c040 is 0 bytes inside a block of size 8 free'd
==5130==    at 0x4C2BDEC: free (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==5130==    by 0x400D16: std::passwd::~passwd() (passwd.c++:19)
==5130==    by 0x400BFA: main (p1.c++:17)
==5130== 
==5130== Invalid free() / delete / delete[] / realloc()
==5130==    at 0x4C2BDEC: free (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==5130==    by 0x400D07: std::passwd::~passwd() (passwd.c++:18)
==5130==    by 0x400C06: main (p1.c++:21)
==5130==  Address 0x5a1c420 is 0 bytes inside a block of size 8 free'd
==5130==    at 0x4C2BDEC: free (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==5130==    by 0x400D07: std::passwd::~passwd() (passwd.c++:18)
==5130==    by 0x400BFA: main (p1.c++:17)
==5130== 
==5130== Invalid free() / delete / delete[] / realloc()
==5130==    at 0x4C2BDEC: free (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==5130==    by 0x400D16: std::passwd::~passwd() (passwd.c++:19)
==5130==    by 0x400C06: main (p1.c++:21)
==5130==  Address 0x5a1c040 is 0 bytes inside a block of size 8 free'd
==5130==    at 0x4C2BDEC: free (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==5130==    by 0x400D16: std::passwd::~passwd() (passwd.c++:19)
==5130==    by 0x400BFA: main (p1.c++:17)
==5130== 
==5130== 
==5130== HEAP SUMMARY:
==5130==     in use at exit: 120 bytes in 1 blocks
==5130==   total heap usage: 7 allocs, 8 frees, 729 bytes allocated
==5130== 
==5130== Searching for pointers to 1 not-freed blocks
==5130== Checked 192,896 bytes
==5130== 
==5130== 120 bytes in 1 blocks are still reachable in loss record 1 of 1
==5130==    at 0x4C2AB80: malloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==5130==    by 0x53C0024: getdelim (iogetdelim.c:66)
==5130==    by 0x5444B52: getpass (getpass.c:97)
==5130==    by 0x400F84: std::passwd::get() (passwd.c++:66)
==5130==    by 0x400B3C: main (p1.c++:9)
==5130== 
==5130== LEAK SUMMARY:
==5130==    definitely lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==5130==    indirectly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==5130==      possibly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==5130==    still reachable: 120 bytes in 1 blocks
==5130==         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==5130== 
==5130== ERROR SUMMARY: 3 errors from 3 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
==5130== 
==5130== 1 errors in context 1 of 3:
==5130== Invalid free() / delete / delete[] / realloc()
==5130==    at 0x4C2BDEC: free (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==5130==    by 0x400D16: std::passwd::~passwd() (passwd.c++:19)
==5130==    by 0x400C06: main (p1.c++:21)
==5130==  Address 0x5a1c040 is 0 bytes inside a block of size 8 free'd
==5130==    at 0x4C2BDEC: free (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==5130==    by 0x400D16: std::passwd::~passwd() (passwd.c++:19)
==5130==    by 0x400BFA: main (p1.c++:17)
==5130== 
==5130== 
==5130== 1 errors in context 2 of 3:
==5130== Invalid free() / delete / delete[] / realloc()
==5130==    at 0x4C2BDEC: free (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==5130==    by 0x400D07: std::passwd::~passwd() (passwd.c++:18)
==5130==    by 0x400C06: main (p1.c++:21)
==5130==  Address 0x5a1c420 is 0 bytes inside a block of size 8 free'd
==5130==    at 0x4C2BDEC: free (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==5130==    by 0x400D07: std::passwd::~passwd() (passwd.c++:18)
==5130==    by 0x400BFA: main (p1.c++:17)
==5130== 
==5130== 
==5130== 1 errors in context 3 of 3:
==5130== Invalid read of size 8
==5130==    at 0x400CFD: std::passwd::~passwd() (passwd.c++:18)
==5130==    by 0x400C06: main (p1.c++:21)
==5130==  Address 0x5a1c040 is 0 bytes inside a block of size 8 free'd
==5130==    at 0x4C2BDEC: free (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==5130==    by 0x400D16: std::passwd::~passwd() (passwd.c++:19)
==5130==    by 0x400BFA: main (p1.c++:17)
==5130== 
==5130== ERROR SUMMARY: 3 errors from 3 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
```

Here is the header file passwd.h

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<iostream>
#ifndef MIN_PASSWD_LEN
#define MIN_PASSWD_LEN 6
#endif
#ifndef MAX_PASSWD_LEN
#define MAX_PASSWD_LEN 20
#endif
#ifndef NO_OF_NUMBERS
#define NO_OF_NUMBERS 1
#endif
#ifndef NO_OF_ALPHABETS
#define NO_OF_ALPHABETS 1
#endif
#ifndef NO_OF_SYMBOLS
#define NO_OF_SYMBOLS 1
#endif
namespace std{
  class passwd{
   char **pwd;
  public:
   passwd& operator=(const passwd);
   passwd();
   ~passwd();
   bool check_validity();
   void tochar(char **);
   void get();
 };
}
```

functions for above header file: passwd.c++

```
#include<iostream>
#include"passwd.h"
#include<string.h>
#include<unistd.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

using namespace std;

passwd::passwd()
{
  pwd=(char **)malloc(sizeof(char*));
  pwd[0]=(char *)malloc(9);
  strcpy(pwd[0],"password");
}

passwd::~passwd()
{
   free(pwd[0]);
   free(pwd);
}

passwd& passwd::operator=(const passwd pswd)
{
  pwd[0]=(char *)realloc(pwd[0],strlen(*pswd.pwd)+1);
  strcpy(pwd[0],*pswd.pwd);
  return *this;
}

bool passwd::check_validity()
{
  if(strlen(pwd[0])<=MAX_PASSWD_LEN&&strlen(pwd[0])>=MIN_PASSWD_LEN);
  else
    return false;
    int number_count=0,alphabet_count=0,symbol_count=0;
    for(int i=0;i<strlen(pwd[0]);i++)
     {
        if(pwd[0][i]<='9'&&pwd[0][i]>='0')
         {
            number_count++;
         }
        else if((pwd[0][i]>='a'&&pwd[0][i]<='z')||(pwd[0][i]>='A'&&pwd[0][i]<='Z'))
          {
            alphabet_count++;

          }
        else if(pwd[0][i]>32&&pwd[0][i]!=127)
          {
            symbol_count++;
          }
      }
if(number_count>=NO_OF_NUMBERS&&alphabet_count>=NO_OF_ALPHABETS  && symbol_count>=NO_OF_SYMBOLS)
      return true;
    else
      return false;
}

void passwd::tochar(char **pswd)
{
  *pswd=(char*)malloc(strlen(pwd[0])+1);
  strcpy(*pswd,pwd[0]);
}

void passwd::get()
{
  char *pswd;
  pswd=getpass("");
  pwd[0]=(char *)realloc(pwd[0],strlen(pswd)+1);
  strcpy(pwd[0],pswd);
}
```

main program: p1.c++

```
#include"passwd.h"
#include<iostream>
#include<stdlib.h> 
int main()
{
  using namespace std;
  passwd p;
  cout<<"Enter password: ";
  p.get();
  if(p.check_validity())
    cout<<"Valid pwd.\n";
  else
    cout<<"Invalid pwd.\n";
  char *s;
  p.tochar(&s);
  cout<<s<<endl;
  passwd x=p;
  free(s);
  x.tochar(&s);
  cout<<s<<endl;
  free(s);
}
```

Comment: It would help if we can see the `passwd` source file too.

Comment: I added passwd source file

Comment: I hope the error is mainly due to assignment x=p

Comment: Just use new and delete in c++ not malloc. Better still use std::string

Comment: I feel this way better to me as I learnt C first , so please tell me whats wrong in above code.

Comment: So learn French to speak Italian?

Comment: Please tell me if you can find the error

Comment: The first thing that's seriously wrong is that you are defining classes in namespace `std`, which is reserved for the compiler. The second thing is that you are using a bunch of `#define`s instead of constants. Then, your header file lacks include guards, but that's minor. Lastly, in C++, there's an important rule, it's called the "Law of Three". Do some research on the web, you absolutely must understand this rule.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your passwd class has an implicitly defined copy constructor. If you don't explicitly create a constructor that looks a bit like

```
passwd(const passwd &other)
```

then the compiler with automatically generate one which simply copies all the members. So when you do

```
passwd x=p;
```

then you effectively do `x.pwd = p.pwd;`. As a result, when the second `passwd` gets destructed, you free `pwd[0]` and `pwd` a second time.

To solve this, explicitly define a copy constructor that does what you want it to do (probably allocate a new `pwd` and `pwd[0]` then copy the password into it). Or, alternately, define a *private* copy constructor to prevent it from being used. Or if you're using a modern constructor you can explicitly delete the copy constructor with `passwd(const passwd &other) = delete;` in the class declaration. Note that the latter two options will make `passwd x = p;` an error.

This breaks even if you do `passwd x; x = p;` due to another issue: Your `operator=` does not take a reference to the original, and so a copy is made when invoking it. Usually one would define an `operator=(const passwd &pswd)` - by leaving out the `&` a copy of the argument must be made, which is done using the copy constructor, which then causes the double-free after you return from `operator=` and the copied `pswd` is destroyed.

Comment: whatif I change the line  `passwd x=p;` to `passwd x; x=p;` ?

Comment: It has to work right?? But still it isn't fine, showing the following error    Invalid read of size 8
    ==7140==    at 0x400D39: std::passwd::~passwd() (passwd.c++:18)
    ==7140==    by 0x400C31: main (p1.c++:22)
    ==7140==  Address 0x5a1c040 is 0 bytes inside a block of size 8 free'd
    ==7140==    at 0x4C2BDEC: free (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
    ==7140==    by 0x400D52: std::passwd::~passwd() (passwd.c++:19)
    ==7140==    by 0x400BD0: main (p1.c++:18)`

Comment: Because `operator=` takes a by-value object, not a reference, the copy constructor is invoked in the process of invoking `operator=`, so the same problem ends up happening.

Comment: can you tell me why we are passing a reference not copy variable